# Add a new image with the existing image list in firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have already two images in the firestore database, I am trying to add a new image to this list? How can I add a new image to the existing image list?

[image: Firebase collection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add another array to the `postImg`, you can:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const colRef = db.collection("user@domain.com");
const docRef = colRef.doc("1fJBcGT8DlZdgbl01LeX");
docRef.update({
  postImg: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("thenewurl");
})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [adding items to an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).